# This Laravel route is returning different responses every time - where do I look for error?

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

This [laravel route](https://resonant-tower-177816.appspot.com/showimage?path=public/images/YxNllK0iVKAxxUSCEhFHLo5sGZiXg5NNbGDbOVSL.jpeg) is returning the image sometimes and is returning an error page the other times. What could go wrong.

This route just returns the image like this:

```
public function image(Request $request) {
    return response()->file(storage_path('app/'.$request->input('path')));
}
```

I'm storing images using this code:

```
    $path = $request->p->store('public/images');
    Storage::setVisibility($path, 'public');
```

I don't know what's going wrong. I see this log when the route is requested.

> NOTICE: PHP message: [2017-09-25 18:33:25] production.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException:
>   The file
>   "/app/storage/app/public/images/YxNllK0iVKAxxUSCEhFHLo5sGZiXg5NNbGDbOVSL.jpeg"
>   does not exist in /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:37

Here's the route in it's full glory:

```
https://resonant-tower-177816.appspot.com/showimage?path=public/images/YxNllK0iVKAxxUSCEhFHLo5sGZiXg5NNbGDbOVSL.jpeg
```

This is definitely not because there's no image there. I can assure you the route works some of the times.

What could have gone wrong?

I'm using Laravel 5.4 on Google App Engine.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is a stupid question. I was running the Laravel on two instances. Apparently, Google Cloud App Engine Flex Environment scales to 2 instances automatically

Answer (score 0):

Wrong path "/app/storage/app/public/images"
The correct path is like "/storage/app/public/images"
So you should change

```
public function image(Request $request) {
return response()->file(storage_path('app/'.$request->input('path')));
```

}
to

```
public function image(Request $request) {
return response()->file(storage_path($request->input('path')));
```

}

Comment: But then why would it work sometimes. Refresh the same route couple of times and I'm sure you'll see the image